# Как написать редирект со всех страниц, кроме выбранной в apache2

Tags: регулярные-выражения, apache2

Нужно в конфиге сайта в apache2 (в директории sites-enabled) написать редирект со всех страниц, кроме "\api\*". Можете подсказать соответствующий регэксп?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой:

```
^(?!\/api\/).+$
```